# Nativescript margin CSS being ignored

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using NativeScript with Angular and have the below `FlexboxLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`. I have created some css classes like `margin-bottom-five` to add margin to some of the elements. This margin is being completely ignore inside the `ScrollView` though.

I assume it is the `ScrollView` causing this behavior because in another template with `FlexboxLayout` but without the `ScrollView` the margins work perfectly. How do I get it to use the margin I specified inside of the `ScrollView`?

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton (tap)="router.back()" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Report"></Label>
</ActionBar>

<ScrollView orientation="vertical" class="page">
    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
        <Label class="text-label margin-bottom-five" textWrap="true">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="Testing"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label>
        <GridLayout *ngFor="let item of items" columns="*,auto,auto,auto,*" rows="auto">
            <Label class="text-label lbl-size" text="{{item.name}}" col="1" textAlignment="center"></Label>
            <Label class="text-label lbl-x-size" text="x" col="2" textAlignment="center"></Label>
            <Label class="text-label lbl-size" text="{{item.date}}" col="3" textAlignment="center"></Label>
        </GridLayout>

        <Button text="Start Over" (tap)="startOver()" class="btn btn-start-over btn-primary">
        </Button>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Css:

```
.margin-bottom-five{
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: u can try including margin-top on `GridLayout` or padding-bottom on `Label` instead

Comment: The margin is 5% but from what? The ScrollView is expecting to measure the content and does not have a predefined size. Try applying a DP intead of percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think that percentage can work in here, try to change it to

`.margin-bottom-five{
  margin-bottom: 5;
}`